# Calculate mode on JTable model

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have no experience with working on `JTables`, how can i make this code co calculate the mode on one of my column?

```
public static int mode(int[] array) {
    int mode = array[0];
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int value = array[i];
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == value) count++;
            if (count > maxCount) {
                mode = value;
                maxCount = count;
            }
        }
    }
    if (maxCount > 1) {
        return mode;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: I'd have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and the JavaDocs for [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), have a go at trying a few things and see where it takes you. If you still have issues, post the code you've tried and we'll see if we can help you further

Comment: I am already calculating min and max on my model, somehow cant get the mode working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the logic of your code, I guess, you should put the `if` condition outside of the inner for loop as shown below.

```
public static int mode(int[] array) {
    int mode = array[0];
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int value = array[i];
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == value) 
                count++; 
        }
        if (count > maxCount) {
            mode = value;
            maxCount = count;
        }
    }
    if (maxCount > 1) {
        return mode;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Though I am not sure actually what exactly you are looking for!

Comment: What im trying to do: i have a Jtable model and i want to calculate the mode on one of the columns.